# Shared Cartfile with private git repo?

Tags: git, swift, carthage

I'm contributing to a Swift project that uses Carthage to manage dependencies. Some of those dependencies are private repos, i.e. the Cartfile contains entries like:

```
git "https://username@bitbucket.org/path/project.git" "master"
```

For simplicity, we would like to be able to share/all use the same Cartfile, but we run into trouble because the link to the private repo requires a username (and Carthage then hangs because it cannot check out the repo).

Is there a (what is the) way for us all to use the same Cartfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they private repositories to which you all have access?  Just remove the username and password from the repository path, or use the `ssh` URL (`git@bitbucket.org:path/project.git`).

http/https urls that require authentication will prompt you for credentials every time. You can use git's [credentials storage mechanism](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) to cache your response or to automatically provide a value.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @larsks!